# How to Select Magento Top-Links

Tags: php, html, css, xml, magento

I am looking to find the correct CSS selector to select this unordered list found in links.phtml:

```
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I was assuming that something like this would work:

```
ul.links li {
    display: inline;
}
```

However it does not. When inspecting with Chrome's developer tools, I can get some of the list items to display inline, but not all of them, or with one simple selector.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

If it helps, the problem can be viewed at www.kokorugs.com/magento

Comment: For me `ul.links li` it's working.

Comment: Hah, you're right. I had mistyped the selector. Thanks, I was going crazy! Please answer the question for credit!